# Laravel whereHas() not filtering by where clause correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm attempting to search players by name and their parents by name/email address.  For some reason the below statement is pulling all players regardless of the search term I enter.

In the below example "guardian" references the `users` table.

```
    $players = Player::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
        ->orWhereHas('guardian', function ($q) {
            $q->where('users.first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
                ->orWhere('users.last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%');
        })
        ->with('guardian')
        ->orderBy('last_name', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(25);
```

Maybe it's just been a long day... but I think I'm missing something.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call with() method before your wheres statements. 
Maybe something like this:

```
     $players = Player::with('guardian')
                ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
                ->orWhereHas('guardian', function ($q) {
                    $q->where('users.first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
                        ->orWhere('users.last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
                        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%');
                })
                ->orderBy('last_name', 'ASC')
                ->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')
                ->paginate(25);
```